# Flask render_template clears all other forms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have multiple forms with one submit button for each of them, all in one template. `render_template` returns only empty `StringFields`. How can I render without touching my other `StringFields`?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    msform = msForm(request.form)
    synform = synForm(request.form)    

    if request.method == 'POST' and msform.validate() and msform.ms_submit.data:
        processed_text = model.most_similar(positive=[msform.ms_3.data, msform.ms_2.data], negative=[msform.ms_1.data])
        msform.ms_submit.label.text = processed_text[0][0]        
        return render_template('my-form.html', msform=msform, synform=synform)        

    elif request.method == 'POST' and synform.validate() and synform.syn_submit:
        processed_text = model.most_similar([synform.syn_1.data])    
        return render_template('my-form.html', msform=msform, synform=synform)

    return render_template('my-form.html', msform=msform, synform=synform)

class msForm(Form):
    ms_1 = StringField(label='Eingabe_1', default = 'king', validators=[validators.DataRequired(message='This Field is required')])
    ms_2 = StringField(label='Eingabe_2', default = 'man', validators=[validators.DataRequired(message='This Field is required')])
    ms_3 = StringField(label='Eingabe_3', default = 'queen', validators=[validators.DataRequired(message='This Field is required')])
    ms_submit = InlineSubmitField(label = '?')

class synForm(Form):
    syn_1 = StringField(label='Eingabe', default = 'king', validators=[validators.DataRequired()])
    syn_submit = InlineSubmitField('?')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have two separate `<form>`s on your HTML page, like this for brevity:

```
<form>{{ msform }}</form>
<form>{{ synform }}</form>
```

I believe you are saying this: upon completing and submitting one form, the values are lost from the other. Is that correct?

If so, that's the expected behavior, not from Flask, but from your browser. When you submit an HTML `<form>`, only the data from that form tag is sent to the server. Therefor, any data in other `<form>` tags is lost.

To submit all forms, render all the forms in the same `<form>` tag. Give each form a prefix to ensure the input names don't collide.

```
msform = msForm(request.form, prefix='ms')
```

```html
<form method="post">
    {{ msform }}
    {{ synform }}
</form>
```